# setIamPolicy for pubsub topics (at the resource level not project)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam, google-deployment-manager

I'm using deployment manager to set the IAM policy of an *existing* pub/sub topic- I don't want to acquire it and I cannot create it with deployment manager (because it exists). So I want to set a policy on an existing resource

I can do this with buckets but the docs are confusing and I can't find the right methods for buckets

I want to do this (resource level bindings) for a topic instead of bucket:

```
resources:
  - name: mybucket
    action: gcp-types/storage-v1:storage.buckets.setIamPolicy
    properties:
      bucket: mybucket
      bindings:
        - role: roles/storage.admin
          members:
          - "serviceAccount:sdfsfds@sdfsdf.com"
```

I can only find `gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics.setIamPolicy` which seems like its at the project level? What is the right api for setting an IAM policy on a specific topic?

The google APIs seem inconsistent here- are these too methods equivalent? Docs are confusing:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/setIamPolicy
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/setIamPolicy

I attempted this but getting an error:

```
  - name: mytopic
    action: gcp-types/pubsub-v1:pubsub.projects.topics.setIamPolicy
    properties:
      resource: mytopic
      bindings:
        - role: roles/pubsub.admin
          members:
          - "serviceAccount:ssdfsdf@sdfsdf.com"
```

Getting error:

```
message: '{"ResourceType":"gcp-types/pubsub-v1:pubsub.projects.topics.setIamPolicy","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"Invalid
    JSON payload received. Unknown name \"bindings\": Cannot find field.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest","fieldViolations":[{"description":"Invalid
    JSON payload received. Unknown name \"bindings\": Cannot find field."}]}],"statusMessage":"Bad
    Request","requestPath":"https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/topics/mytopic:setIamPolicy","httpMethod":"POST"}}
```

When I tried projects.topics.setIamPolicy I got:

```
- code: COLLECTION_NOT_FOUND
  message: Collection 'projects.topics.setIamPolicy' not found in discovery doc 'https://pubsub.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'
```

Comment: I found this nugget ... https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/sqladmin  which says "Actions are a currently undocumented feature for calling arbitrary APIs.".  Well ... huh!!!

Comment: thats funny its not documented. I gave up on their docs a little while ago and started looking for examples in the wild- i never realized that feature was totally undocumented

Comment: On a philosophical standpoint ... I'm thinking that we may have an impass on the notion of creating or updating a resource that already exists and not having it "owned" by Deployment Manager.  What is the thinking on why having the resource owned by Deployment Manager is a bad thing?  I'm also thinking that if we don't want it owned by Deployment Manager we can run DM twice ... once to update the resources and once to delete your resources using the ABANDON policy for deletions.

Comment: if you could ABANDON at the resource level that would solve my issues. The problem is there are resources localized to this stack and shared resources this stack/deployment should never own the lifecycle of. So the deployment can be freely created and destroyed without destroying shared resources. having a separate deployment specifically for modifying existing resources and using ABANDON there would work but I dont love that- id like this to be a single template/deployment. also, my needing resource level policies stems from having a poor project structure I currently cant change

Comment: Could you provide me additional information concerning the missing information in our documentation? an example would be nice, I could then file a documentation request to have it added.

Comment: @danyL sure! Maybe this isn't supported yet but I want to set an IAM policy on a specific topic with a deployment manager _action_. actions arent documented but the GCP APIs of course are. If you look at the two links in my question im trying to find the right API call to apply a policy to a topic like I can with GCS. Cant find an example in the pub/sub docs i linked to. Its possible to set a policy on a topic via the web console and with gcloud but I cant find docs for setting it via deployment manager action or even what method it should even call to do that. Thanks!

Comment: @danyL there doesnt seem to be a "JSON API" for pub/sub so maybe this is why its not possible to do this with deployment manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pubsub-v1:projects.topics.setIamPolicy`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/setIamPolicy) is at the topic level and the [`https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/{resource=projects/*/serviceAccounts/*}:setIamPolicy`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/setIamPolicy) is to set the a Pub/Sub or other resources at the project level.

You get those error because you are giving Pub/Sub admin and this is a role at the project level. The example [roles](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/Policy#Binding.FIELDS.role) you can provide are:

- roles/viewer
- roles/editor
- roles/owner

I understand that you are trying to to deploy a topic having a IAM policy that allows only one service account to a topic. You have to use a yaml file and a python file if that is the environment you are using.

In the [python file](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#setting_a_policy) you will set the IAM for the topic with the method "set_iam_policy" which takes 2 arguments, the policy and the topic path:

```
client = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = client.topic_path(project, topic_name)

policy = client.get_iam_policy(topic_path)

# Add all users as viewers.
policy.bindings.add(
    role='roles/pubsub.viewer',
    members=['allUsers'])

# Add a group as a publisher.
policy.bindings.add(
    role='roles/pubsub.publisher',
    members=['group:cloud-logs@google.com'])

# Set the policy
policy = client.set_iam_policy(topic_path, policy)

print('IAM policy for topic {} set: {}'.format(
    topic_name, policy))
```

For [deployment manager](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/community/cloud-foundation/templates/pubsub/examples/pubsub.yaml):

```
imports:
  - path: templates/pubsub/pubsub.py
    name: pubsub.py

resources:
  - name: test-pubsub
    type: pubsub.py
    properties:
      topic: test-topic
      accessControl:
        - role: roles/pubsub.subscriber
          members:
            - user:demo@user.com
      subscriptions:
        - name: first-subscription
          accessControl:
            - role: roles/pubsub.subscriber
              members:
               - user:demo@user.com
        - name: second-subscription
          ackDeadlineSeconds: 15
```

Comment: would you be able to provide a working example with a deployment manager action? Is it `action: gcp-types/pubsub-v1:pubsub.projects.topics.setIamPolicy` or `action: gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics.setIamPolicy` ? Also, is "resource level policy" the right name for what this is? Is there a good high level-ish doc that lays out the difference between project and resource level access control including how the APIs differ there?

Comment: if its not possible with a deployment manager _action_ thats fine but I wanted to use that to avoid having to script the APIs. Is it possible with an action?

Comment: Using managers actions is not possible at the moment for this